# How to get random with beta distribution in PHP 7?

Tags: php, random, statistics, php-7, pecl

I am trying to get random number with [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) in PHP 7. I found function [stats_rand_gen_beta](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-beta.php), but when I was trying to install it by command:

```
sudo pecl install stats
```

I obtained the following error

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/stats requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.6.99), installed version is 7.0.14-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
No valid packages found
install failed
```

How to handle with this? Is there any replacement for `stats`, or other method to simply generate random with given distribution of probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem checking website https://pecl.php.net/package/stats. There was written, that I should install second version of this package https://pecl.php.net/package/stats/2.0.3

O [this](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-stats-extension.html) blog I found instruction of installation.

Problem is fully solved.

## Update

Finally i do not use stats, because I had problem with generating the same number any time.

I found great library:

https://github.com/gburtini/Probability-Distributions-for-PHP

Instalation:

```
composer require gburtini/distributions
```

Usage:

```
require_once "vendor/gburtini/distributions/src/gburtini/Distributions/Beta.php";

$a = 1.1;
$b = 9.3;

$beta = new \gburtini\Distributions\Beta($a, $b);
$res = $beta->rands(20);

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: gburtini is great, but unfortunately doesn't implement a number of functions (PDF, CDF, etc.) for the beta distribution.

Comment: It is opensource. We can make fork and implement them, equations for CFD is quite complicated. I propose create issue, add these functions and add pull request or switch to python :D

Comment: I need it in PHP, the rest of my app is Symfony. :-)
I'd fork it if I felt sure enough with the math, but I don't.

Comment: Ok. So please type in issue, which functions do you need and assign me (@gustawdaniel) in this issue. But now I see also one problem, for example for CFD we need choice among time of calculation and precision. Please tell more about usage in your project so I will be able to calibrate these calculations.

Comment: I see https://github.com/gburtini/Probability-Distributions-for-PHP/issues/31 you can type in this issue instead create new one.